# Make array from regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I have this string:

```
{example1}{example2}{example3}
```

This is the regular expression to find these `{` `anything in it` `}`:

```
/\{.*?\}/g
```

Now I want to know how put them in an array so I can do a `for in` statement.

I want an array something like `array("{example1}","{example2}","{example3}");` ?

Comment: If you've got an actual Array, you'd be much better off using a simple `for` loop rather than a `for...in`, which may give you more than you bargained for: all extensions to `Array`'s prototype will be listed, as well as the items in the array.

Comment: You shouldn't be iterating arrays with `for-in`.  Use a C-style `for` loop, preferably.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
your_array = string.match( pattern )
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: Will this make an array such like `array("{example1}","{example2}","{example3}");` ?

Comment: he's a beginner i think you won't help him by posting those function singatures ;)

Comment: @zolex true. I like to at least link to w3schools instead of the straight documentation, as they have examples and the "try it now" feature.

Answer (score 14):

```
var matches = '{example1}{example2}{example3}'.match(/\{.*?\}/g);
// ['{example1}', '{example2}', '{example3}']
```

[See it here](http://jsbin.com/enopi4/).

Also, you should probably use a `for` loop to iterate through the array. `for in` can have side effects, such as collecting more things to iterate through the prototype chain. You can use `hasOwnProperty()`, but a `for` loop is just that much easier.

For performance, you can also cache the `length` property prior to including it in the `for` condition.